# Console App that produced a form(Windows Form)?

Tags: c++, c, windows, visual-c++

How can I create a windows form using a console app? Like when I run the console app it will show a form(windows form). Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to understand, how windows in Windows works. Each windowed program manages something called a message queue. Messages are informations from system (and other applications), that something happened, for example someone pressed a key or moved a mouse, such that window can react to that user action properly.

Processing messages (including dispatching them to proper window) is a responsibility of the program and in Windows Forms applications is done in Application.Run method (or somewhere near that) by some internal message processing loop. But if you want to display a window in your console application, someone has to take responsibility for this process, otherwise window won't work correctly (actually, they won't work at all).

If you display a window modally, it will process messages coming to it by itself, so you can call directly `myWindow.ShowDialog` from your code and that will work - but will lock console *input* away until the window is closed. That means, you will be able to send text to console by `Console.WriteLine`, but you won't be able to - for instance - ask user for text by `Console.ReadLine` until the window is closed.

```
class Program 
{
    public static void Main(string[] args) 
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.Form f = new System.Windows.Forms.Form();
        f.Click += (o, e) => { Console.WriteLine("Clicked!"); };
        f.ShowDialog();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

// (run, then click on a form to observe result)
```

If, on the other hand, you want to display a window in a non-dialog way, things get complicated. The simplest thing comming to my mind is to create Windows Forms application and use [AllocConsole](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681944%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to create separate console window for application (for example Blender does that). The other option is to create two different applications - console and Windows Forms one, run the second from the first and manage their communication by some mechanism (named pipes, shared global memory, windows messages, TCP/IP etc.)

Answer (score -1):

It is not directly supported no.

What you could do is have two separate applications, one form and one console. Start the console one from the form one and pass data between the applications. If you want to set the form to be "inside" the console application you can use

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984420%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: What do you mean by "not directly supported"? Add reference to `System.Windows.Forms` and then write in your console application: `System.Windows.Forms.Form f = new System.Windows.Forms.Form(); f.ShowDialog();`

Comment: The question is phrased "How can I create a windows form using a console app?" You can not do that directly. And you can not link them together as one window either, you can however (as I pointed out) make the illusion of it.

Edit: I shouldn't say you can't, one probably can, but not as far as I am aware of any conventional means.

Comment: What can be more conventional from instantiating a form and calling ShowDialog on it? You even can quite simply add a Windows Form to the console project and edit it in VS designer. I fail to see what is "not directly supported" here. "Uncommon", maybe. BTW the opposite requires ~1 line of code (adding console support to WF application)